(Revelation 17:17) The "ten kings" giving their kingdom to the "beast", what is that about?
What different opinions exist on what the text in Revelation 17:17 refers to?
The passage says, according to NKJV

For God has put it into their hearts to fulfill His purpose, to be of
one mind, and to give their kingdom to the beast, until the words of
God are fulfilled.


There are many different opinions about the meaning of Revelation 17:17.  In order to avoid opinion-based answers, you need to specify which religious group or denomination you seek answers from.

In order to answer thoroughly, identification of who "they" are must be made. Whose hearts has God so affected that they will fulfill his will? Verses 15 and 16 show that identifying them depends on understanding who "the whore" is, what the 10 horns of the beast represent as to why they turn upon this symbolic 'wanton woman' to destroy her (which is God's will).
That particular 'beast' must be identified. (There is more than one 'beast' in Revelation.) Only then can its 10 horns be interpreted as to what they mean, in terms of 'agreeing'. What do they agree about that leads to giving their kingdom (singular) to that particular beast?
The scope of this question is quite massive. As personal opinions are discouraged on this site, I will conclude by quoting from a 614 page book that delves deeply into the entire book of Revelation. There are four basic interpretative stances. This has been written from what is generally called the 'Historicist' view (which is what the Protestant Reformers had). However, the author more accurately calls it the Resumptive Interpretation, as the interpretation is based on seeing how the book of Revelation repeats 7 times the global events foretold, each succeeding opening resuming the warnings, from the start to the Last Day. Revelation chapter 17 begins again the account of history for the sixth time. But this time, more details are added. Obviously, if one had a grasp of the previous five openings, this sixth one would be quite easy to grasp. Revelation verses 9 to 13 identify the kings (rulers, governors):

"The seven heads are seven mountains, on which the woman sitteth. And
there are seven kings: five are fallen, and one is, and the other is
not yet come, and when he cometh, he must continue a short space. And
the beast that was, but is not, even he is the eighth, and is of the
seven, and goeth into perdition. And the ten horns which thou sawest
are ten kings, which have received no kingdom ass yet; but receive
power as kings one hour with the beast. These have one mind, and shall
give their power and strength unto the beast." Revelation 17:9-13
K.J.V.

Now comes a bit of an explanation (there is no way all the relevant points in this book can be copied). Bear in mind that the author views the Revelation as being spiritual and symbolic - not literal.

"The ungodly and unrighteous cohabitation of the kings or rulers with
these concepts - summed up under the figure of the whore, and
whole-heartedly embraced by them - is that which they are convinced
guarantees them their place of government over a satisfied populace.
This is called 'fornication' on the part of the 'kings' with the
mystical whore, just as the peoples' acceptance of their social
engineering in lieu of godly and righteous government is called being
made drunk by the wine of the whore's fornication. The fact that the
whore is invisible and intangible, actually no more than an amalgam of
ideas, concepts, ways, means, and forms, does not alter the truth that
were that amalgamation suddenly to be made visible, or become
embodied, then that appearance or embodiment would answer to the
figurative description of the whore...
...the seven heads of the beast indicate perfect earthly intelligence,
seven being the number of perfection, and the head being the seat both
of understanding and perception. This mystical symbol answers to the
dragon, also possessed - in the figure - of seven heads, Chapter 12:3.
While both beast and dragon are portrayed in allegorical and visionary
imagery, of the two the dragon is the figurative form of an existent
being, called the Devil, and Satan, whereas the beast is a mystical
figure depicting a creation of the mind and ingenuity of Satan... It
is through his seven heads that the accrued perfection of intelligence
and wisdom conspicuous in the seven-headed dragon pursues its earthly
objective.
'The seven heads are seven mountains, on which the woman siteth.'
...The meaning is, that when the invisible dragon is permitted to
gather all his forces to assert his power among all nations, striving
for world dominion and universal government, he enlists not only the
contemporary head of the beast, but also all the allure and seduction
of the woman...
...The ten kings give their power with one accord and one mind to the
beast, and, if so, to the concept of world government represented by
the seventh and last head and personified by the presiding rule of the
final governor, leader, or king...
...the seventh king [is] rather a chief among equals, a president of
world executives; that is, one 'king' having the allegiance of ten
'kings' in the highly allegorical language of the text. But ten kings
answers to complete - or world-wide - rule or government... the
complete number of rulers of the nations with one mind give their power
and their strength to the concepts enunciated by so sagacious a lead.
Spiritually - though unknowingly - this is to give their power and
strength to the beast. The Revelation of Jesus Christ, John Metcalfe,
pages 456 & 468-469, 473-474, 1998
http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm

You asked what verse 17 is all about. This answer is only a tit-bit, to let you see how no 'sound-bite' answer will suffice. The only way you could get the full understanding would be to studiously delve into the entire book of Revelation, for the tiny part you ask about has information relating to it in the five preceding sections. Revelation 17:17 is in the sixth section, so I've had to jump in at the deep end here. You need to start at the beginning, the shallow end, wade your way into increasingly deeper 'waters' until you swim the whole length through to the end! That book would enable you to do that.

Since the question is "What views exist", I can legitimately offer the approach followed in my own book ("Silence in heaven").
We know from v12 that they are working together with the beast, and acting under his authority. "Being of one mind and giving their kingdom to the beast" repeats that theme.. That is the conscious motivation of what they are doing.
But there is unconscious motivation as well, implanted by God. There is a parallel to this possibility in the account of Gog prince of Magog in Ezekiel ch38. There we are told, on the one hand, that "thoughts wll come into your mind and you will devise an evil scheme" (v10) which will prompt him to attack God's people. But we are also told, on the other hand, that even this is God's doing; "I will bring you forth" (v4).
In the same way, the rest of Revelation ch17 v17 is telling us that God is providing the unconscious motivation for what the ten kings are doing. God has put it into their unconscious minds, with the intention, on his part, that they should thus carry out his purpose, providing one of the stages in his overall plan of salvation (the defeat of his enemies) and fulfilling his word. The word being fulfilled could be this verse, or the prophecy in Ezekiel ch38, or the overall promise of final victory (that is, the whole of Revelation).

Are you talking about Divine mind control or is it more in line with the giving over principle in the latter part of Romans chapter 1?

@Mike Borden The metaphor in Ezekiel is closer to (semi) "mind control", and we probably have to think in those terms if we are being told that God's purpose is being fulfilled in the process. Another example is the case of the Assyrians in Isaiah ch10; God says he sent and commanded them to act as his agents of judgment (vv5-6), "but he did not so intend... it is in his mind to destroy" (v7).

That is, God's prompting acts in conjunction with human will in ways which we cannot easily disentangle, and I suspect this happens much more frequently than we can ever imagine.

Revelation 17 is at the end of the prophecies of Daniel and Revelation, so if you have studied them in order, it will help to identify this one. Verse 12 says the ten kingdoms have received no kingdom as yet. When they receive this power, they give it to assist the beast in persecuting. The joint kingdom (state) will give power to the religious entity (church) and when these are combined there is always persecution. This is God's will prior to the close of human history for the purpose of bringing the final events into being. The state and church combined will persecute God's people for a short period.  Suddenly there is a change in thinking, and they hate the beast/religious entity and seek to destroy it/her.  We must wait for its fulfilment to know what causes this hatred, but it could be the preaching of the final message which identifies all parties, and has latter rain power of the Holy Spirit.

Is your answer based on the views of J. Nelson Darby? I ask because an answer from a Catholic perspective is asked for.
